# Javascript - regex for matching a string literal `log` after opening a function

Tags: javascript, regex, string, webpack

I'm trying to write a simple webpack loader which will automatically write console logs if a string literal appears after a function's opening brackets.

For example:

```
function myFunc(arg1) { "log" ...
```

Would become

```
function myFunc(arg1) { console.log("myFunc", arguments) ...
```

Since webpack will load files as strings, I'm using the `string.replace` method, beginning with a regex which at the moment only matches the string `"log"`. Obviously that's pretty rigid, so I was hoping a regex aficionado might help me accomplish a couple things:

1. Match `"log"` and  `'log'` alike (double or single quotes - I know I could just do `"log"|'log'`, but I imagine there's a cleaner way).
2. Capture the name of the function in the regex (i.e. `myFunc` in `function myFunc() {...` or `var myFunc = function() {...`). It's possible this can't be done with a regex, but I keep reading about "lookaheads" and "negative lookaheads" which sound like features that do what I'm looking to do.

Obviously I have a lot to learn about regular expressions, so any help with this concrete problem will really help me along. Any help/information is much appreciated.

Comment: Not super simple to do, but I think a babel transform plugin would be the way to go with what you are trying to do: https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md#transformation-operations - parsing is generally more reliable approach than regex string manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a seemingly simple task turns out to be much more complex than you might think at first. The problem with using regular expressions for this, is that you need to have a very specific pattern that you can match on. JavaScript's function definitions are too versatile to find a simple regular expression for them.

Let's only consider the named function declaration (`function name(args) {}`) for the moment. You might think that starting from the `function` keyword, then capturing the name and looking for `{ "log"` is a decent choice, because the opening curly bracket starts the function body. This does work for simple arguments but it will fail for object destructuring. For example:

```
// Take an object as argument, look for the `log` property and assign it to `arg`
// Remember that object keys can be strings
function destructure({ "log": arg }) { return arg; }
destructure({ log: 42 }); // returns 42

// Invalid function after transformation
function destructure({ console.log("destructure", arguments);: arg }) { return arg; }
//                            ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected Token .
```

For more details about destructuring see [Exploring ES6 - Chapter 10. Destructuring](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html).

You can fix this case by including the closing parenthesis of the arguments list, which means you would be looking for `) { "log"` instead. Unfortunately, that is not good enough either. An example that involves default parameters with an object literal that has a method, would at least not produce a syntax error, but it is semantically incorrect.

```
// If the argument is not given (undefined), use the specified object
function defaultParam(arg = { defaultMethod() { "log"; } }) { "log"; }

// Logs in the wrong function or the wrong name respectively
function defaultParam(arg = { defaultMethod() { console.log("defaultParam", arguments); } }) { "log"; }
```

There are no simple patterns left you could use to find the beginning of the function body and any step further would involve finding the matching parentheses, for which there is no regular expression for the general case, as they would be recursive patterns and regular expressions don't support recursion.

*Note: Some languages do have regular expression recursion, but JavaScript is not one of them*. Have a look at [Regular Expression Recursion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html) for a brief description.

As you've asked for a regular expression, I will explain a regular expression that should work for function declarations without default parameters.

```
(                   # Start capture group for everything before "log" (will be $1)
    function        # function keyword
    \s+             # One or more spaces, to avoid matching: functionVariable etc.
    (               # Start captured group for the function name (will be $2)
        [^\s\(]+    # Any character except spaces or opening parenthesis (at least one)
    )               # End captured group for the function name
    \s*             # Optional spaces between name and opening parenthesis
    \(              # Opening parenthesis
    [^\)]*          # Any character but the closing parenthesis (arguments, which are optional)
    \)              # Closing parenthesis
    \s*             # Optional spaces between closing parenthesis and opening curly
    {               # Opening curly bracket to start the body
    \s*             # Optional spaces between starting the body and the "log"
)                   # End captured group for everything before "log"
("log"|'log')       # The actual log string
;?                  # Optional semicolon
```

Notice that the first group (`$1`) captures everything up until the `"log"` string. The reason is that you want to keep that and only replace the `"log"` string, but because you're matching it, you'll need to include it again in the pattern you want to replace it with. The name is available as `$2` and the replacement pattern would be:

```
$1console.log("$2", arguments);
```

You can see it in action on [Regexr](http://regexr.com/3gveq).

The JavaScript version:

```
text.replace(/(function\s+([^\s\(]+)\s*\([^\)]*\)\s*{\s*)("log"|'log');?/g, '$1console.log("$2", arguments);');
```

> Match "log" and  'log' alike (double or single quotes - I know I could just do "log"|'log', but I imagine there's a cleaner way).

An alternative to `("log"|'log')` is to capture the opening quote and match the same character that has been matched again after `log`. As we have already used two capture groups, it will be `$3` and it can be accessed it in the regular expression with `\3`.

```
("|')log\3
```

As a tiny bonus you can use the same quotes in the replacement that were used in the `"log"` string.

```
$1console.log($3$2$3, arguments);
```

---

## Babel plugin - A much better solution

Regular expressions are clearly not the right tool for the job. A better solution is to write a parser for it. Thankfully you don't need to do that, because there are various JavaScript parsers out there, which you can use. With [Babel](https://babeljs.io) you can go a step further and transform the code fairly easily by creating a Babel plugin. Chances are very high that you are already using Babel, so all you'd need to do is add the plugin to your `.babelrc`.

To get started you should read the [Babel Plugin Handbook](https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md) and use [AST Explorer](https://astexplorer.net) to look at the AST produced by Babel. As a bonus, you can even write the Babel plugin in the AST Explorer by selecting Babel in the Transform menu.

If you paste your example into AST Explorer, you'll find out that the `"log"` string is not just a simple string, but it's a directive. You might have encountered the [`"use strict";` directive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) before, which enables strict mode. We can use that fact to visit all `Directive` AST nodes and modify the AST if needed.

Let's start by creating the Babel plugin, which is a function that returns an object with a visitor on it. For details see [Writing your first Babel Plugin](https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md#writing-your-first-babel-plugin). We only care about a visitor for `Directive` nodes, so it looks like this:

```
export default function({ types: t }) {
  return {
    visitor: {
      Directive(path) {
        // Find "log" directive and replace it with a console.log call
      }
    }
  };
}
```

`t` has a lot of helpful methods to operate on AST nodes. We will use `t.isDirectiveLiteral(node, opts)` to find out whether the `value` of the `Directive` is actually `"log"`. The `t.isX(node, opts)` methods check whether the given `node` is of type `X`, where is `X` is any AST node type which you can easily find out in the AST Explorer. Additionally it will check whether the node contains the properties specified in `opts`. See also [Check if a node is a certain type](https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md#check-if-a-node-is-a-certain-type).

```
if (t.isDirectiveLiteral(path.node.value, { value: "log" })) {}
```

When it is the `"log"` directive, we need to find the name of the function. First, we need to find the enclosing function, which can be done with [`path.getFunctionParent()`](https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md#find-a-specific-parent-path).

Now that we have the function, we need to find its name. This will be the only tricky part. When it's a function declaration, we can use it's name. When it's a function expression, we need to find the name of the variable it is assigned to, which coincidentally will be the parent of the function expression. It can also be a method on an object, but that is the same concept except that it's an `ObjectMethod` instead of `FunctionDeclaration` and an `ObjectProperty` instead of `VariableDeclaration`. That are at least the named functions I can think of, so we will use these and everything else will be considered an anonymous function.

```
const fnDefinition = path.getFunctionParent();

let name = "anonymous";
if (t.isFunctionDeclaration(fnDefinition.node)) {
  name = fnDefinition.node.id.name;
} else if (t.isVariableDeclarator(fnDefinition.parent)) {
  name = fnDefinition.parent.id.name;
} else if (t.isObjectMethod(fnDefinition.node)) {
  name = fnDefinition.node.key.name;
} else if (t.isObjectProperty(fnDefinition.parent)) {
  name = fnDefinition.parent.key.name
}
```

Next, we can create an AST node that represents `console.log("name", arguments);`. That will be a `CallExpression` where the callee is `console.log` and the arguments will be a `StringLiteral` with the value `log` and the identifier `arguments`. Similar to the `t.isX` methods, there exist methods on `t` to create an AST node, which have the same names as the AST nodes, but start with a lowercase character, e.g. [`t.callExpression(callee, arguments)`](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-types#callexpression).

```
const logNode = t.expressionStatement(
  t.callExpression(t.identifier("console.log"), [
    t.stringLiteral(name),
    t.identifier("arguments")
  ])
);
```

Lastly, we [insert the node into the body](https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md#inserting-into-a-container) of the function and delete the `Directive` node, as we no longer need it in the resulting code.

```
fnDefinition.get("body").unshiftContainer("body", logNode);
path.remove();
```

Full code:

```
export default function({ types: t }) {
  return {
    visitor: {
      Directive(path) {
        // Check that it's the "log" directive
        if (t.isDirectiveLiteral(path.node.value, { value: "log" })) {
          // Find the enclosing function definition
          const fnDefinition = path.getFunctionParent();

          // Look for a possible name for the function otherwise use "anonymous"
          let name = "anonymous";
          if (t.isFunctionDeclaration(fnDefinition.node)) {
            name = fnDefinition.node.id.name;
          } else if (t.isVariableDeclarator(fnDefinition.parent)) {
            name = fnDefinition.parent.id.name;
          } else if (t.isObjectMethod(fnDefinition.node)) {
            name = fnDefinition.node.key.name;
          } else if (t.isObjectProperty(fnDefinition.parent)) {
            name = fnDefinition.parent.key.name
          }

          // Create an AST node that corresponds to console.log("name", arguments)
          const logNode = t.expressionStatement(
            t.callExpression(t.identifier("console.log"), [
              t.stringLiteral(name),
              t.identifier("arguments")
            ])
          );
          // Insert the node into the beginning of the function's body
          fnDefinition.get("body").unshiftContainer("body", logNode);
          // Delete the directive, it's no longer needed
          path.remove();
        }
      }
    }
  };
}
```

The full code and some test cases can be found in [this AST Explorer Gist](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/498c1bcebad8550f1dc1ba2b24128518/6db6e5f74604e97a68ec0512818f85345a19ece6).

That was a lot easier than fiddling with the regular expression and it works for every case like the default parameter object with a method from above. Additionally, it also works for arrow functions, without having to change anything.

Helpful resources:

- [Babel Plugin Handbook](https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md)
- [`babel-types`](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-types)
- [AST Explorer](https://astexplorer.net/)
- [Code Transformation and Linting with ASTs - FrontendMasters course by Kent C. Dodds](https://frontendmasters.com/courses/linting-asts/)

Comment: Michael, I couldn't have asked for a more thorough, informative, or well-reasoned answer - thank you so much! There's definitely a lot to digest here, and a whole bunch of new concepts I'll want to explore in the coming weeks. I think I'm going to start off with a simple loader which uses the regex - your suggestion and [this tutorial](regexone.com) helped me come up with a few patterns I'll use in sequence. I'm going to come back and try to understand the babel plugin you wrote, and maybe try to release that somewhere (with credit to you of course!). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try a more popular approach: method decorators.

```
@log
    myMethod = function(foo) {
}
```

http://derpturkey.com/function-wrapping-with-javascript-decorators/

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely want to use a regular expression, the following hopefully does what you want to do (if I understood your question):

```
var a = "function myFunc(arg1) { \"log\" ...";
var b = "function     abc(argument,arg,  argument_test   )\n\n\n{  \n 'log' ...";
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
a = a.replace(/function(\s*)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(\s*)\((\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\s*(?:,\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\s*)*)\)(\s*){(\s*)(?:"|')log(?:"|')/g, "function$1$2$3($4)$5{$6console.log(\"$2\", arguments);");
b = b.replace(/function(\s*)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(\s*)\((\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\s*(?:,\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\s*)*)\)(\s*){(\s*)(?:"|')log(?:"|')/g, "function$1$2$3($4)$5{$6console.log(\"$2\", arguments);");
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

If I run the code above, I get the following output:
[image]

If you want to know more about the regular expression, leave a comment and if you want to learn about regular expressions in general, I recommend a tutorial and the following webpage which can be really helpful: https://regexr.com/